# Powershell: the -file option breaks array parameters

Tags: bash, powershell

I have to call a powershell script with one parameter from a bash environment, then I have the following command line:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -File ./myScript.ps1 param1
```

This is actually not working as the -File option breaks the flow and makes powershell to think that the file is './myScript.ps1 param1'.

There is a nice comment at the end of this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx).

Is a pitty that in this comment there is not a single example how to avoid this.

I have tried with something like this with no luck:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -command ./myScript.ps1 -myparam param1
```

In short my question is, how can I call from a bash environment a powershell script with arguments?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here an image that shows exactly the output I get:

[image: *Bash* output]

Powershell version is:
Major: 2, Minor: 0, Build: -1 and Revision: -1

Comment: That comment refers to array notation being interpeted as strings. That is not the issue here. I am going to test but you dont say what you mean by _This is actually not working_. What PowerShell version do you have and what issues are you seeing exactly.

Comment: If I have the script `param([string]$this) write-host "$this is that"` then run the command in cmd `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -File .\this.ps1 This` then i get the result in console "This is that"

Comment: Perhaps we need to see the real example of what you are doing and at least a portion of the script itself.

Comment: Try running [echoargs](https://chocolatey.org/packages/echoargs) with your arguments and tell us what result you get.

Comment: @Matt cmd is working fine, the problem is when using bash. You can give it a try using _Cygwin64 Terminal_